# How to update subset of NuGet Packages in entire solution

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I would like to be able to update specific NuGet packages for the entire solution via the command line so I can use it as part of my build process inside a build Target.

Currently, I'm using the target below - which constrains the NuGet update to a local source.

This has a number of drawbacks.  Firstly its per project.  So I can't run it once of one for all the projects and update 'all' the other projects.

Next any updates to build process don't propagate until the next build.  So if there are any subsequent changes to NuGet package files or Targets, you have to run it twice.

Secondly is errors on packages it cannot resolve dependencies for (understandably).

So is there a way to update a specific list of Nuget Packages for every project via the command line, i.e. from a batch file I can run - so each project is using the latest version of a specific package?

```
    <Target Name="Update" Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)packages.config')" BeforeTargets="CreateManifestResourceNames">
        <Warning Text="Warning - Updating all packages from $(NetworkNugetPath)"/>
        <Exec Command="$(ToolsPath)NuGet.exe update $(ProjectDir)packages.config -Source $(NetworkNugetPath) -FileConflictAction Overwrite -NonInteractive" IgnoreExitCode="true"/>
    </Target>
```

Note this is .Net framework project so I can't use any of the new core functionality.

Comment: If you update 20 NuGet packages and something breaks, how will you know which update is causing the problem? Dependencies must be managed and reviewed by developers, not updated will-nilly.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can manage NuGet packages for the solution. In solution explorer, right click on solution and select "Manage NuGet packages for Solution...".

Comment: @Ian Kemp In the use context that they are being used in.  Which is developing a package, so build pack cycle in 30-40 times a day.  So how would work around this.  Also that's why I stated specific packages, i.e. ones which are under my control.

Comment: @Verno I'm looking for a command-line option,  as development and build process is Visual studio agnostic.

Comment: @GregoryWilliamBryant Are these organisation-internal packages? I.e. you have an app dependent on those packages, there is a bug in one of them, you update that package, now you want to update all dependent apps? In that case, it should still be a single package update though?

Comment: @Ian Kemp,  this is the business case I'm working with.  'Rightly' or 'Wrongly' I want the new packages to propagate.   I have to repo A containing packages,  and repo B consuming them.   I don't want to use frozen in time dlls, I can't do project references as they will fail at TFS build stage. So NuGet has been opted to distribute the shared code.

Comment: Also, I don't believe the question merits a downvote.   If the answer is 'it can't be done'  then that should be expanded upon in question answer.  If its, it can be done, but it is an anti-pattern to do so - that should form the answer.  Downvotes are to curate whether a question is well-formed and 'can' be answered.   Not to express whether something is good or bad practice is it?

Comment: Do you have try `dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json --version 12.0.3 --no-restore`. The option `no-restore` skip [compatibility check](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package#options). You can use dotnet cli with .NET Framework.

Comment: @Vernou will dotnet CLI interact with old-style packages.config and project files.  As it there where the dependencies will need to be updated.  Also, in your example, you are specifying a specific version, whereas I want the 'lastest'.

Comment: I tested on legacy project with classic csproj and this work. To get the last, just remove the option `--version`. But you need to have the list of csproj. Maybe PowerShell script can return all `.csproj`files.